# How can i resolve this error the 'connectionStringName' attribute is not allowed in web.config of asp.net in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

How can i resolve the issue of connectionStringName' attribute is not allowed in visual studio in mvc 4 asp.net

`web.config`

[image]

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVE-20171019175539;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
<add name="SchoolContext"    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\university.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

`Web.config`                 `// Line 60 column 189 the code below`

```
    <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" 
    type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, 
    System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
    </providers>
```

Comment: That is a warning. Not an error!

Comment: How can i resolve it?

Comment: Remove that attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVE-20171019175539;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

from your connection strings. You don't need it since you're using 'SchoolContext'.

Remove as well:

```
<providers>
<add name="DefaultSessionProvider" 
type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, 
System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
</providers>
```

You're not using any sort of authentication are you?